# openpose issue when running the example: check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0) out of memory, result in core dumped

Tags: caffe, openpose

Does anyone encounter this issue when using the openpose 1.7 under ubuntu 20.04?
I cannot run the example provided. It will simply core dumped. CUDA version 11.3, Nvidia driver version 465.19.01, GPU geforce rtx 3070.

```
dys@dys:~/Desktop/openpose$ ./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --video examples/media/video.avi 
Starting OpenPose demo...
Configuring OpenPose...
Starting thread(s)...
Auto-detecting all available GPUs... Detected 1 GPU(s), using 1 of them starting at GPU 0.
F0610 18:34:51.300406 28248 syncedmem.cpp:71] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f63e2bc51c3  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f63e2bca25b  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f63e2bc4ebf  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f63e2bc56ef  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7f63e28ffe2a  caffe::SyncedMemory::mutable_gpu_data()
    @     0x7f63e27796a6  caffe::Blob<>::mutable_gpu_data()
    @     0x7f63e293a9ee  caffe::CuDNNConvolutionLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
    @     0x7f63e28bfb62  caffe::Net<>::ForwardFromTo()
    @     0x7f63e327a25e  op::NetCaffe::forwardPass()
    @     0x7f63e32971ea  op::PoseExtractorCaffe::forwardPass()
    @     0x7f63e329228b  op::PoseExtractor::forwardPass()
    @     0x7f63e328fd80  op::WPoseExtractor<>::work()
    @     0x7f63e32c0c7f  op::Worker<>::checkAndWork()
    @     0x7f63e32c0e0b  op::SubThread<>::workTWorkers()
    @     0x7f63e32ce8ed  op::SubThreadQueueInOut<>::work()
    @     0x7f63e32c5981  op::Thread<>::threadFunction()
    @     0x7f63e2f04d84  (unknown)
    @     0x7f63e2c07609  start_thread
    @     0x7f63e2d43293  clone
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: check `nvidia-smi` output to see if the GPU has it's memory in use by another process or user.  If so, reboot the machine (or notify other user, or kill process, etc.)

Comment: before starting the openpose program it's 488MiB /  7959MiB . I am using watch nvidia-smi now, right before it core dumped. It has a memory of something nearly full.

Comment: So  whatever you are trying to do is using too much memory for your GPU.

Comment: base on the Doc, if cuDNN is properly working, this should not take more than 2.2 gb Vram, maybe I messed something up